# how to use Hangfire in separate write/read databases in CQRS pattern

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, cqrs, hangfire, hangfire-sql

As you know in cqrs pattern we may use separated databases for write data (command) and read data (query).
I want to know in this case if I want to use Hangfire how should I specify that which database hangfire should connect to?
Is it possible to separate write/read databases in hangfire?

I saw [this](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-start-multiple-hangfire-servers-1-web-application-multiple-databases/2305) solutions but it doesn’t resolve my concerns.